# How to solve set of equations Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a set of equations defining a system. I have no idea how to do this in Matlab, other than the fact that it is possible, and iterations are required.

I have three equations with three unknowns (`Q`, `T_a_out` and `T_b_out`).

The system is divided into several sub-parts. Information about the temperature in the first and the last sub-part must be used to find the temperatures in the sub-parts in the middle. I need the `Q`, `T_a_out` and `T_b_out` for each sub-part.

[image: System description]

The equations used to describe the system are as follows:

```
Q=U*((T_a_out-T_b_in)+(T_a_in-T_b_out))/2
Q=m_a*(cp_a_in*T_a_in-cp_a_out*T_a_out)
Q=m_b*cp_b*(T_b_out-T_b_in)
```

These parameters are known:

```
Initial T_a_in (110)
Initial T_b_in (5)
U
m_a
m_b
n (number of sub-parts)
cp_b
```

The `cp` value is a function of the temperature it belongs to:

```
cp_a_in is a function of the temperature: cp_a_in=function_a(T_a_in)
cp_a_out is a function of the temperature: cp_a_out=function_a(T_a_out)
```

The initial `a` value (110) has a higher value than the final `b_out` temperature in the last sub-part. The initial `b_in` value (5) has a lower value than the final `a_out` value.

How can I calculate the `out` temperatures for each sub-part in Matlab?

Comment: Does the initial `T_a_in` and `T_b_in` stay **constant**, or do these change when you're trying to find the solution to the system?

Comment: How are your `cp` functions defined? This is likely to be important.

Comment: On top of what Jubobs asked, if you could also provide the exact definitions of your `cp` functions (code and all), that would be helpful in understanding and perhaps solving your problem.

Comment: @rayryeng: They stay constant.

Comment: @ROLF - Great.  That makes my life easier.  What about the `cp` functions?

Comment: @Jubobs: I'm using a non-freeware function called REFPROP. `cp=refpropm('C','T',temperature,'P',pressure,'co2')`. `pressure` is known. `co2` defines what substance I'm investigating. `C` only tells the function what sort of value I`m looking for.

I can't provide the `refpropm` function code. I have a student licence of this commercial software.

Comment: @ROLF - Does `cp` stay constant throughout the solving, or do these values change?

Comment: @rayryeng: `cp` is only dependent on temperature (and pressure, which is known). `cp` for a given temperature is constant, but `cp` change from temperature to temperature.

Comment: @rayryeng: cp and temperature are not proportional, but increasing temperature results in increasing cp value. [link](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/carbon-dioxide-d_974.html) Don't know which pressure these values are for, but you might get an idea.

Comment: Do you know cp_b? If so, then your system if equations is overdetermined. Equating any two if the equations for `Q` gives you the same number of equations as unknowns. A physical meaning of the math is that your overall heat transfer coefficient  `U` either captures the heat capacities (aka heat exchange) meaning that's the only equation you need, or you need two additional temperatures accounting for the heat transfer from the hot side to the cold side of the heat exchanger. Which is it?

Comment: @pragmatist1: I have assumed a constant cp_b, so the value is both known and constant. I'm afraid I didn't really catch the two alternatives you are mentioning. What do you mean by "capturing the heat capacities"? BTW: `U` is actually `U times A`, but I guess you understood that. I wrote it as `U` in order for people not familiar to thermodynamics not to be (additionally) confused. `UA` is at the moment considered constant. If time, `U` will be made dependent on velocities (but that's not relevant now).

Comment: @ROLF: If you say equations 2 and 3 for `Q` are equal, then you are saying that there is *no* heat loss between them. You actually have three equations and 2 unknowns. If you want to account for inefficiency through `UA` then you introduce two more temperatures,  corresponding to a heat transfer medium (say some metal) that would exchange heat with Ta_in, and transfer it to Tb_in. So: Ta_in <---> Tmiddle_1 <-- UA --> Tmiddle_2 <--> Tb_in. Either that or you eliminate the other two relationships.

Comment: I'm trying to make a (much) simpler model of [this PhD model, page 195](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:125093/FULLTEXT01.pdf). As far as I remember, Stene did not calculate surface temperatures for the metal separating CO2 and water. Do I understand you right if you say that in order to use `UA` as restriction for heat transfer, surface temperatures of the metal must be calculated? Isn't the metal accounted for in the `UA` value?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments I've put together a quick script that should get you started in the right direction - in addition to a few notes.

The first is that what you are trying to solve is non-trivial, especially considering that the Cp(T) is highly nonlinear and on top of that diverges near the critical point.

Also, recognizing that H = CpdT, and you're using REFPROP, a more accurate calculation would be H(T_out) - H(T_in) which would incorporate temperature effects.

With that being said, by writing out your mass balances you can formulate a system of non-linear equations to solve as shown below. Since I couldn't resolve your use of `UA` I just substituted in an "effectiveness factor". Feel free to use your convention of choice (say, NTU) to fill that in.

I caution you that what I've posted below is **incomplete**. It's a starting point and there are a few issues to consider:

I am specifying `n-2` temperature variables while providing `n` equations meaning that the bounds are likely to be satisfied as Ta_end = Tb_end (you will see what I mean if you run it and plot). This also potentially cause a discontinuity in temperature as a function of stage.

Depending on your pressures and fluids, if you are going through a 1st order phase transition you may experience some weird numerical issues.

If you can assume a constant heat capacity you can reformulate the matrix below into a much easier and solvable system. I provide this more complex example as a starting point.

```
function Tf = gen_mat
n = 10; % Number of stages 
A = zeros(n,2*n+2); % Coefficients matrix.

ma = 10; % Mass flow of A.
mb = 5;  % Mass flow of B.
eff = 1.0; % Effectiveness factor.
Te(1) = 383.15; % Inlet T of A.
Te(2) = 278.15; % Inlet T of B.
P = 15000; % P (kPa)

% Generate guesses 
Ti = linspace(Te(1),Te(2),n+1)';
Tg = zeros(2*n+1,1);
for i=1:n+1
    Tg(2*i-1) = Ti(i);
    Tg(2*i) = Ti(i);
end
Tg([1,2*n+1]) = []; % We are only interested in the middle sections.

% construct coefficient matrix.
for i=1:n
    A(i,2*i-1) = -ma;
    A(i,2*i) = eff*mb;
    A(i,2*i+1) = ma;
    A(i,2*i+2) = -eff*mb;
end

% solve system of nonlinear equations
Tf = fsolve(@(T)obj_fxn(T,A,P,Te), Tg, optimset('Display', 'iter'));
Tf = [Te(1);Tf;Te(2)]; % Append temperatures.
end

function b = obj_fxn(T,A,P,Te)
T = [Te(1); T; Te(2)];
for i=1:2:length(T)-1
    x(i) = refpropm('H','T',T(i),'P',P,'CO2');
    x(i+1) = refpropm('H','T',T(i+1),'P',P,'water');
end
b = A*x';
end
```

You can create a crude plot of the above after running it like this:  `plot(0:10,Tf(1:2:end)-273,10:-1:0,Tf(2:2:end)-273)`.

Sorry that this is not more organized, but I hope it helps.